# Android webview cookie not working like chrome

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a page which contains some checkbox to mark as voting purpose. When opening this page using chrome and voting and after reopening its showing the correct state of checkbox mark . But when doing same thing using android webview its not working.
Can any one help regarding this.
I have already added code for `cookiemanager.setAcceptCookie(true)` and also `cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview , true)` but its not working.

Also after reopening in android webview and clicking on other component and coming back the change is reflecting.

Comment: have you called `setWebChromeClient` on your webview?

Comment: Yes @AlexTimonin